# How to find out what is blocking my OpenVPN traffic

Tags: networking, firewall, openvpn

I am having a problem getting my OpenVPN push route to work.

My setup is the following

**Network**

- Homelan: 10.0.0.0/24 with
- OpenVPN: 10.8.0.0/24
- VPS in Internet

**Servers (all Linux)**

- Server1: 10.0.0.13 + 10.8.0.1 (the OpenVPN Server)
- Server2: 10.0.0.11 (DHCP+DNS)
- VPS: Internet IP + 10.8.0.X (random IP from OpenVPN)

**OpenVPN Server config**

```
..snip..
push "route 10.0.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 10.0.0.11"
..snip..
```

**IP forward activated**

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

**Route VPS**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         www.xxx.yyy.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.5        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
www.xxx.yyy.1    *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

**Route Server1**

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.0.0.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
```

Try to ping the openvpn-server (10.8.0.1) from VPS

```
ping 10.0.0.13
ping 10.0.0.13 -I tun0;#gives same result
```

**tcpdump of VPS**

```
tcpdump -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
19:05:22.049141 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17966, seq 1, length 64
19:05:22.101397 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 17966, seq 1, length 64
```

**tcpdump server1**

```
tcpdump -i tun0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
18:05:22.064139 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17966, seq 1, length 64
18:05:22.064399 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 17966, seq 1, length 64
18:05:23.065687 IP 10.8.0.6 > 10.8.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 17966, seq 2, length 64
18:05:23.065886 IP 10.8.0.1 > 10.8.0.6: ICMP echo reply, id 17966, seq 2, length 64
```

What is not working is the connection from the VPS to the internal IP of Server 1

Try to ping the openvpn-server (10.0.0.13) from VPS

**tcpdump of VPS**

```
19:12:24.847216 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18136, seq 1, length 64 
19:12:25.876441 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18136, seq 2, length 64 
19:12:26.900408 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18136, seq 3, length 64 
19:12:27.924476 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18136, seq 4, length 64 
19:12:39.964724 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18137, seq 1, length 64 
19:12:40.980446 IP vps.hoster.tld > 10.0.0.13: ICMP echo request, id 18137, seq 2, length 64
```

**tcpdump of Server1**

```
#stays empty
```

So I am really wondering what is wrong here.
What would be the next step to find out what is blocking my traffic from the VPS to the internal IPs of 10.0.0.0/24 ?
Maybe a firewall in the homelan is blocking the traffic? How to find out?

Comment: Show the 'iptables -L INPUT -n' and 'traceroute 10.0.0.13'.

Answer (score 0):

**Reaching Internal Interface, No Routing**
By default Linux will respond to any of its IPs on any interface, it will even respond to ARP requests on the "wrong" interface. This is super insecure, so most firewalls will block this behavior using iptables and proc/arp_filter.

You may have firewall rules that block routing in:

`server1> iptables -L -n -v`

`server1> iptables -t nat -L -n -v`

`server1> iptables -A FORWARD -j LOG` will log(dmesg) all packets that are routed between the 10.8 and 10.0 through server1. It might give you some info.

`$server1> iptables -D FORWARD -j LOG` to remove the rule.

The following will insert routing rules before any firewall rules.
`server1> echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`
`server1> iptables -I FORWARD 1 --in-interface tun0 --source 10.8.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`
`server1> iptables -I FORWARD 1 --in-interface eth0 --source 10.0.0.0/24 -j ACCEPT`

I wouldn't expect `VPS> ping 10.0.0.11` to work, but if it does the problem is almost certainly in server1's iptables.

You are routing through server1 on a point to point, so it shouldn't be doing ARP, but if either of these are set to 1 it was probably done by a firewall script and the problem will be in server1's iptables.
`server1> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_filter`
`server1> cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/arp_filter`

**Routes**
Your routes look good, but with this setup you don't need the 10.8.0.0/24 ones in there.  10.8.0.1 to 10.8.0.5 is point-to-point.

VPS should have a `default gw`, `10.8.0.1 via tun0`, and `10.0.0.0/24 via gw 10.8.0.1`.
server1 should have a `default gw` and `10.8.0.5 via tun0`, and `10.0.0.0/24 via eth0`.